# 2010 Hyundia Elantra, are these repairs necessary?

Tags: elantra

I don't know much about cars so I am looking for some honest feedback on recommendations made by the dealership I have been taking my car to. I am a little thrown off because my extended warranty just ended, and now they say I need all these things done... Are these necessary maintenance items? Or which ones would you recommend?

- Tune Up: Plugs and Wires ($265)
- Cabin filter ($60)
- Coolant Service ($170)
- Induction Service ($135)
- Sway Bar Link ($90)

Thanks in advance for any advice you can give me.

Comment: cabin filter you should be able to do yourself without tools for about $10-20.

Comment: Is this a 4-cyl or 6-cyl? (Assuming 4, but just wondering.)

Answer (score 1):

The first four of those are general service items - so it very much depends on the service schedule of the car (which should be listed in the handbook) - as an example, a quick search suggests that Hyundai recommend changing the coolant every 30,000 miles (so if your car has done a multiple of 30k, it's probably due). None of them would have been covered by the warranty anyway, as warranties never cover service items.

The sway bar link is a maintenance item, so we have no way of telling through the internet if it needs changing - but if in doubt, get a second opinion from another local mechanic.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your mileage. Platinum plugs last 100,000 miles. Most modern cars have a coil on each plug, so don't need "wires". "Induction" may just be a $ 20 air cleaner ; probably a good idea, maybe do it yourself. I don't know what a "tune-up" is on a computer controlled engine ;I haven't had one in 25 years.

Answer (score 0):

It would all depend on mileage, if you had it for 7 years at 12k miles you're about close to the 100k mileage mark.

If you're a diy'er than most of these things would cost like half what's quoted.

The spark plugs and wires are general wear items about 100k and you'd wanna replace them but their not difficult for a diy'er either if it's a 4 cylinder engine.

Cabin air filter is located behind the glove box so it's also easy to replace with a little guidance. Part would be under $15 and generally takes 20 minutes the first time you try it.

The coolant and induction are good ideas to perform as the coolant prolongs the life of all the engine parts. The induction is a cleaning that will help improve performance and fuel economy.

The sway bar links should be inspected, but if they're not making noises what's causing the dealer to suggest replacing them?